# Compose - How to draw additional content inside a custom layout's MeasurePolicy

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have created a custom layout which simply receives some items and stack them like a column.

```
MyCustomLayout(
    modifier = modifier,
    items = {
        Component1()
        Component2()
        Component3()
        Component4()
        }
    },
)

@Composable
private fun MyCustomLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    items: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        contents = listOf(items),
    ) { itemsMeasurable, constraints ->
        if (itemsMeasurable.isEmpty()) {
            layout(0, 0) {}
        } else {
            // Measure the items
            val itemsPlaceable = itemsMeasurable.map {
                it.measure(constraints)
            }
            // Layout width is the max width of the items
            val layoutWidth = itemsPlaceable.maxOf { it.width }
            // Layout height is the sum of the items
            val layoutHeight = itemsPlaceable.sumOf { it.height }

            // create a layout with size of the items
            layout(layoutWidth, layoutHeight) {
                // Place the items like a column
                var yPosition = 0
                itemsPlaceable.forEach { placeable ->
                    placeable.placeRelative(0, yPosition)
                    yPosition += placeable.height
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works just like a Column and works fine.
What I need is to add a divider after each item. Of course I can add a divider after each Component like

```
MyCustomLayout(
    modifier = modifier,
    items = {
        Component1()
        Divider()
        Component2()
        Divider()
        Component3()
        Divider()
        Component4()
        }
    },
)
```

But it feels wrong and I'd like this to be the responsibility of the custom layout to draw the divider. Is it possible to draw anything while placing the items (inside MeasurePolicy scope)?

I tried this but of course it doesn't work because it's not inside a composable function context.

```
itemsPlaceable.forEach { placeable ->
    placeable.placeRelative(0, yPosition)
    Divider()
    yPosition += placeable.height + DividerHeight
}
```